# validate large JSON keys

Tags: json, swift, validation, parsing

I receive large JSON data and I need to know if any key is nil.

I generally do a thing like this (using SwiftyJSON):

```
guard let
 name = json["username"].string,
 firstEpisodeAiredText = json["firstEpisodeAired"].string,
 firstEpisodeAired = formatter.dateFromString(firstEpisodeAiredText),
 seasons = json["seasons"].int,
 genres = (json["genres"].array?.flatMap { $0.string })
else { return nil }
```

Problem is I can have hundreds of keys coming from the same request:
is there any simpler way to test my keys against nil value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all keys in `SwiftyJSON` are not optional so they could not be **nil**.

Secondly to validate all data of the JSON you should iterate each element of the JSON.

Example :

```
class func validation(with json:JSON) -> Bool {

    guard let jsonDictionary = json.dictionary else {
        return false
    }

    let keys = jsonDictionary.keys //All keys of the Dictionary 

    for key in keys {

        guard let data = jsonDictionary[key] else { //If data is nil return false
            return false
        }

        print("JSON data: \(data)")
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Oleg, if name = json["username"].string is not nil is because username is a string, am I wrong? So, validating it this way tells me if the key contains the right kind of data. That said, I could even have an entity declared as optional. 

Keys can even be deeply nested.

Comment: @3000 you should recursively check each element  of the JSON tree and validate type.

Comment: I sincerely hoped there was some Swift functional "magics" to avoid this recursion. Thanks very much for your kind reply